# How to change the delimeter in a file to make a csv

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, delimiter

I have a file that is formated to be split by `|` characters. Since I am used to manipulating CSVs I assume it would be preferential to have all of the `|` turned into `,`.

I normally open my CSVs using functions such as

```
with open('minitest.csv', 'rb') as f:
```

Does this need to be edited to open files that are delimited by `|` or is it best to convert them all to `,`. I am kind of leaning towards the latter already since so much of my coding is based around maipulating CSVs.

Comment: Use the `csv` module when you are working with csv files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and tell it to use `|` as a delimiter:

```
import csv

with open('minitest.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
```

A correctly configured `csv.reader()` object will read your pipe-separated files just fine.